# Replace certain field from file with user input for each row and save in same file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh, gawk

Im typing to write a script which can read **file_name**, **delimiter** and **field_number**. After that for each row take an input, replace the field (specified by **field_number**) and output to same file.

For example if the input is as follows:

```
Ritesh;M;1992
Shakya;F;1993
```

For the command

```
bash_script.sh test.csv ";" 3
```

Iterating through each row if I input **1994** for first and 1995 for second. I want the output to be the as follows caved in the same file.

```
Ritesh;M;1994
Shakya;F;1995
```

So far i managed to get upto this point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Following is the input needed:";
echo "\$1: FILE_NAME";
echo "\$2: DELIMITER";
echo "\$3: FIELD IN NUMERIC VALUE";

gawk -i inplace -F "$2" '{...}' $1;
```

Also my version of `gawk` doesn't support -i.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your gawk doesn't support -i, why is it in your example of what you have up to now... ?

Comment: your script input are `test.csv` `v` and `3` then you would transform `1992` in `1994` and `1993` in `1995`. is it right?

Comment: @123 I can just write to a tmp file and mv it into place afterwards or some similar method anyway, So that wasn't a major concern . Was just mentioning it.

Comment: @claudiom input is test.csv, delimiter ";, field to modity 3. and the rest as you said it.

Comment: @riteshakya037 which is the replacing logic? `1994` for `M` and `1995` for `F` ?

Comment: Ritesh;M;1992 -> Ritesh;M;**1994**

Shakya;F;1993 -> Shakya;F;**1995**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to first question**

If you only need to replace `1992` with `1994` and `1993` with `1995`, you don't need a script, you can do it easily using sed:

```
sed "s/;1992/;1994/g" test.csv | sed "s/;1993/;1995/g"
```

Output:

```
[shell] ➤ sed "s/;1992/;1994/g" test.csv | sed "s/;1993/;1995/g"
Ritesh;M;1994
Shakya;F;1995
```

If you also need to save the output you can add

```
sed "s/;1992/;1994/g" test.csv | sed "s/;1993/;1995/g" > temp; mv temp test.scv
```

But if you want to use a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "${1}" ];then
        echo "Usage: $0 <filename>"
else
        FILENAME=$1
        sed "s/;1992/;1994/g" $FILENAME| sed "s/;1993/;1995/g"
fi
```

Output:

```
[shell] ➤ ./test3.sh
Usage: ./test3.sh <filename>

[shell] ➤ ./test3.sh test.csv
Ritesh;M;1994
Shakya;F;1995
```

**Script updated after last comment**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "${3}" ];then
        echo "Usage: <filename> <delimiter> <field_no>"
else
        FILENAME=$(readlink -f $1)
        DELIMITER=$2
        FIELD_NO=$3
        TEMP_FILE=/tmp/tempFile
        if [ -f $TEMP_FILE ]; then
            rm $TEMP_FILE
        fi
        for line in $(cat $FILENAME)
        do
                oldValue=`echo $line|cut -d$DELIMITER -f$FIELD_NO`
                echo "Enter the value to replace [$oldValue]"
                read newValue
                echo $line | sed "s/${oldValue}/${newValue}/g" >> $TEMP_FILE
        done
fi
mv $TEMP_FILE $FILENAME
```

I've commented the command `#mv tempFile $FILENAME` because it's your choice to rename the file or keep the new one.

Comment: actually I wanted to replace the column no matter what the value. And for each row, prompt to enter a value.

Comment: Do you only need to replace the 3th column with what?I mean, where do you get the value for replacement? Please try to explain better which is the purpose if this script.

Comment: i was wondering if i could input the value for each line i.e. the script prompts me for a value for 1st row, updates the value, moves to second, then asks for the 2nd value.

Comment: That's another requirement ... that's completely different from what you asked in your question! btw I'll try to add the answer

Comment: @riteshakya037 did you check the last change on my answer? Is that what you looking for?

Comment: yeah totally what I wanted. Thanks for all the help. (like)

Comment: I'm glad to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using sed is always my opt out;

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
DELIM=$2
FIELD=$3

REPLACEMENT="XXX"
sed "s/[^$DELIM]*/$REPLACEMENT/$FIELD" $FILE
```

If it needs to be something calculated from the current value, you need to loop each line and extract it.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
DELIM=$2
FIELD=$3

while read line; do
   value="$(echo $line | cut -d"$DELIM" -f$FIELD)"
   if [ "$value" == "1992" ]; then REPLACEMENT="1994";
   elif [ "$value" == "1993" ]; then REPLACEMENT="1995";
   fi
   echo $line | sed "s/[^$DELIM]*/$REPLACEMENT/$FIELD"
done < $FILE
```

Comment: actually I wanted to replace the column no matter what the value. And for each row, prompt to enter a value.